# What <<>> means in sequence diagram?

Tags: uml

I know that `<<>>` is for specifying the view layer,
However, I saw some examples and the DataAccess is like this `<<DataAccess>>`, is there an explanation behind it ?

[image]

Comment: There’s some context missing here. ˋ<<>>ˋ is for indicating keyword and stereotypes. Stereotypes are means to extend UML notation (and some tools allow to hide/show stereotyped elements). Any diagram to share to facilitate our understanding ?

Comment: check the image for the example I referred to

https://img.onl/zvlS6V

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That just looks bogus. This is a stereotype and the object has neither name nor type. You would likely need to ask the diagram author for an explanation. Without you can interpret it at will (if you like or allowed to). My interpretation is that is some object which has at least a `WriteDB` and a `find` operation.

Comment: I see, I only have the image so I can't contact the author. 

Thanks!